# trying to create helm charts for ingress

Tags: parameters, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

iam trying to create helm charts for this ingress.yaml and i already set parameters for being able just ] to change hosts name for specs > tls> hosts & specs > rules > host

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:

  annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "8k"

  name: ingress-example

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts: {{ .Values.ingress.hostname }}
    secretName: secret-example
    
  
  rules:
  - host: {{ .Values.ingress.extraTls.hosts }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: 
          servicePort:
```

this is my values.yaml file :

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: example.com
  extraTls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
```

when i try to deploy it giving me very long error i cant past it here but iam sure that my syntax is wrong, i tried too much examples without success. can anyone tell me the right syntax ?

Comment: Without the error it's hard to know where to begin. Note however that `The extensions/v1beta1 and networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 API versions of Ingress is no longer served as of v1.22.`  https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#ingress-v122